# Two Main methods with different signatures

Tags: java, program-entry-point

I have following class.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(Integer[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is not a main"); 
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This is the main"); 
    }
}
```

In here there are two `main` method which are accept `Integer[]` and `String []` as input argument. My question is how `JVM` always load second method as main method of this class. Why always consider input argument as `array` of `String`?

Comment: Design decision based on SLaks' comment.

Comment: Because that's what a command line is.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183611/using-int-instead-of-string-public-static-void-main-int-args

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because that's what Java always looks for.  [Java Language Specification, Section 12.1.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4):

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of String

Answer (score 5):

Because Strings are what you're passing into the command line.

the `45` from

> myProgram.exe 45

is not an integer.  it is a string containing the characters `4` and `5`

It just so happens that you can use a string like `"45"` to represent an integer.  It's a little more difficult to do it the other way around.(for the user at least)

Comment: ...Because you can pass Integers as String, whereas String as Integer is rather limited.

Answer (score 4):

Since command line arguments are always `Strings`.

Answer (score 2):

We always enter **command line args as Strings**. :)

Answer (score 1):

Aside from what others have mentioned, you can use var-args to implement String array.

```
public static void main (String ...a)
```

Answer (score 0):

For further information check this doc

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

And also

[Using int Instead Of String: public static void main (int[] args)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183611/using-int-instead-of-string-public-static-void-main-int-args)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the `main` method will always be called by the JVM with the overload that takes a string array. You are free to make other overloads to that metod if you so wish. You may even call them yourself in your code. It's just that the VM specifically looks for that one overload that takes an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only signature recognized by the JVM as *THE  MAIN METHOD*

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

You can have as many overloaded main method as you want BUT only the method with the above signature will be called by the jvm

Answer (score 0):

Command-line arguments are arguments to the `main()` method which are passed to it at run-time. Since Java uses only `String` type command-line arguments, the JVM ignores the other `main()` method which passes Integer.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the main method in java is `public static void main(String[] args) {}` and that is what the JVM's classloader loads at the start of the program. The other main with an Integer argument won't be called unless you did it manually inside main. Try modifying your code as shown below and you'll notice that nothing will be called and your program won't print anything.

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(Integer[] args) {
      System.out.println("This is not a real main so nothing gets printed"); 
  }   
}
```

Btw, you can write an overloaded main method with any argument that you want. As long as the argument is not **String[] or String...** which are the same, nothing will start rolling the program.