# Beginning Java Programming in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is my code so far. I know there is something really really trivial that I am missing. I am a beginner C++ programmer as well but still do not have much experience in that language either.

I just want this to print out if I have made the mark or not. Next I will ask for an input from the command prompt and respond accordingly. Right now the command prompt opens when I click run and that is it... No lines printed! Also there are no errors...

```
public class CheckPassFail {
    public static void main(CheckPassFail[] args){
        int mark=88;
        System.out.println("The mark is " + mark);

        if(mark >= 50){
            System.out.println("You Passed!");
        } 
        else{
            System.out.println("You Failed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args)` Main must have this signature which requires a String, not your custom object (you can change the variable name args to anything however). Also, see the other allowed signature from assylias's answer.

Comment: Change the arguments of your `main` to `String[] args`.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of main has to be one of:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
public static void main(String... args)
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18194838/829571

Answer (score 2):

`public static void main` expects its arguments to be of type String:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Should fix your problem.

Comment: Its not of type **String** its of type **String[]**