# error when calling main method with parameters

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class classroom{
public static void main(Integer[] args) {
    int teachers = args[0];
    int students = args[1];
    int desks = args[2];
    int computers = args[3];
    double ratio = students/desks;
    if (teachers == 1) {
           if (computers >= students) {
               if (ratio <= 6) {
                   System.out.println("this classroom is vald");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("this classroom is not valid");
        }
    }
}
```

I run the code as classroom.main(1, 2, 3, 4), and java returns the following error: 'identifier expected'. Any idea how I should solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean "I run the code as classroom.main(1, 2, 3, 4)"? How do you do that? Also, your logic appears to be off in terms of displaying whether a classroom is "vald" or not. And doing integer math to boot.

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure you posted what you try to run? In what line do you get the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using int Instead Of String: public static void main (int\[\] args)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183611/using-int-instead-of-string-public-static-void-main-int-args)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should solve this problem call method as:

```
Classroom.main(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `...` operator, Calling `Classroom.main(1, 2, 3, 4)` will require you to change the method Argument with three dot operator. By using Three dot operator `...` You can pass integer arguments without explicitly creating array.

```
public class ClassRoom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassRoom.main(1, 2, 3, 4);
    }
    private static void main(Integer... args) {
        for (Integer i : args) {
            System.out.println("Argument [ " + i + " ] = " + args[i-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function by `classroom.main(new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 })`, instead of `classroom.main(1, 2, 3, 4)`.
Because the function declares as `classroom.main(Integer[] args)`, but not `classroom.main(int a, int b, int c, int d)`.

Another advice: Java class name should use Camel Case for the Java naming convention.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't decorate your posts with a signature; you already get a user card with a link to your profile beneath each submission. See also [how not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)